# Pands json_normalize with extra empty columns according to a schema

Tags: python, json, pandas

How do I enforce pandas to add extra columns with only NaN values using a schema. I have data formatted as JSON records, but when a field doesn't exist for a record, there's no keys for it in the JSON representation instead of a NaN value. For some columns in the schema that I'd like to have, there's no data of it in any records, so it doesn't show up in the JSON object and pd.json_normalize won't make a column for it. How do I enforce the results of pd.json_normalize to have all the columns according to the schema, and have a column of all NaN if there's no data available for that column.

Here's an example of the data I have and the desired format:

```py
data = [
    {'foo': 'foo_value', 'bar': {'1': 'bar1', '2': 'bar2'}},
    {'foo': 'foo_value_2'}
]
desired_columns = ['foo', 'bar.1', 'bar.2', 'nodata.1', 'nodata.2']
```

If I use pd.json_normalize, I get:

```py
>>> pd.json_normalize(data)
           foo bar.1 bar.2
0    foo_value  bar1  bar2
1  foo_value_2   NaN   NaN
```

Instead, I'd like to get:

```py
           foo bar.1 bar.2  nodata.1  nodata.2
0    foo_value  bar1  bar2       NaN       NaN
1  foo_value_2   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set empty columns with `json_normalize`. So you will either have to set them manually:

```
import numpy as np
df["nodata.1"] = np.nan
df["nodata.2"] = np.nan
```

Or add `nodata` to the first list item prior to loading it in pandas:

```
data = [
    {'foo': 'foo_value', 'bar': {'1': 'bar1', '2': 'bar2'}},
    {'foo': 'foo_value_2'}
]

data[0]['nodata'] = {'1': np.nan, '2': np.nan}

pd.json_normalize(data)
```